# put 2 value as key and value into an obj array

Tags: javascript

I have the following arrays:

```
var key = [a,b,c],
val = [10,20,30];
```

How can I produce result like this:

```
[{a:10},{b:20},{c:30}]
```

I stuck at here

```
var final = [];
key.forEach(function(i){

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply iterate through the array and collect the data in required format:

```js
var key = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var val = [10, 20, 30];

var result = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < key.length; i++)
{
  var obj = {};
  obj[key[i]] = val[i];
  result.push(obj);
}

document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(result, null, 2) + "</pre>";
```

However, in my opinion, your desirable format is pretty inconvenient to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Basically when defining object elements you have two options either `object.property = value` or `object["property"] = value` (See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties) for more information on this).  So in your case you can do this -

```
var key = [a,b,c],
var val = [10,20,30];

var final = [];
key.forEach(function(currentKey, index){
  final[currentKey] = val[index];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the forEach loop with the second parameter that gives the index:

```
function combineToObjectArray(array1, array2) {
var result = [];

if ((typeof array1 === "object") && (typeof array2 === "object") && (array1.length === array2.length)) {
    array1.forEach(function (element, index) {
        var key = element,
            obj = {};
         obj[key] = array2[index];
        result.push(obj); 
    });
}
return result;
```

}

I created a small fiddle to test it: https://jsfiddle.net/wnyto2q4/11/